# Ejecutar archivo cada cierto tiempo en PHP

Tags: php, ajax, cron

Estoy desarrollando una web que extrae información de una API de manera automática y constante, por lo cual necesito ejecutar un archivo

```
archivo-extraccion.php
```

La idea principal era utilizar un cron para poder obtener la ejecución de este archivo que simplemente extrae un valor y lo crea o actualiza en mi base de datos.
El problema es que mi hosting en las tareas programadas me otorga como mínimo de tiempo 5 minutos y yo necesito que sea de 1 minuto o máximo 2. ¿De qué manera podría realizar de manera automática éste proceso con este margen de tiempo?

Comment: Cron es el camino. Si tu hosting te limita a intervalos de tiempo mínimos de 5 minutos no creo que puedas engañar al hosting de otro modo. Queda como alternativa cambiar de hosting o usar herramientas tipo Firebase para actualizaciones en tiempo real.

Comment: @A.Cedano a modo consulta, no sé si lo sabes pero pregunto de todas maneras, a qué se debe que el hosting limite a 5 minutos? Y con alguna función que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo tampoco es posible? Pregunto con desconocimiento total a sus formas.

Comment: El negocio del alojamiento es lograr meter cierto número de sitios en un solo servidor y, para ello, los proveedores deben cuidar que nadie consuma demasiados recursos. Las limitaciones de este tipo generalmente vienen de allí.

Comment: Negocio, por todo lo que te ha dicho @jachguate en su comentario. En cuanto a escribir algo que se ejecute cada 1 minuto,.estamos en lo mismo: ¿cómo vas a lanzarlo? Cron es la mejor herramienta para esto, y la más ligera. Si el hosting te lo limita, ¿te permitirá hacerlo por otra vía que además es más costosa? O, supongamos que lo logras. En cuanto haya cierta concurrencia (X cantidad de usuarios ejecutando código cada 1 minuto en el servidor), el hosting te mandará una advertencia invitándote a contratar un VPS  y a detener esa práctica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mi solución seria la siguiente: haría el llamado desde javascript:

```
function hacerPeticion() {
    $.post("archivo-extraccion.php", {
        data: "de_ser_necesario"
    }, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}

// Llamar a hacerPeticion cada 60 segundos
setInterval(hacerPeticion, 60000);
```

esto lo pondría en un archivo html y lo dejaría abierto.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta definitiva a esto es adquirir un plan de alojamiento que te permita programar las tareas con la frecuencia que necesitas. Va a ser más caro, seguramente, pero va a ser más estable y seguro.

Sin embargo, puedes intentar un *workaround* como el siguiente.

Prepara un script que contenga el código actual de tu script dentro de una función, y luego haga la ejecución de dicho código, digamos 4 veces, con una espera *cercana* a un minuto entre cada una. Para la espera puedes valerte de `sleep()`.

Incluso, puedes asegurarte que la ejecución sea más precisa cada minuto midiendo el tiempo que se tarda cada una, ese es ya un ejercicio que te quedaría a tí.

La idea básica es:

```
<?php
for ($contador = 0; $contador < 4; $contador++) {
  realizar_extraccion();
  sleep(58);
}
?>
```

Acá estoy asumiendo muchas cosas:

- que la extracción dura unos 2 segundos y, entonces, *durmo* el proceso por 58 segundos, para que se ejecute aproximadamente al minuto.
- que no se requiere una alta precisión en el tiempo de ejecución, por lo que el resultado es aceptable.
- que tu proveedor no va a monitorear y matar procesos que tarden más de cierto límite pre-programador ejecutándose.

Con esto, ya puedes programar dicho script en CRON para que se ejecute cada 5 minutos. Si el período en el que se va a ejecutar es distinto, o la frecuencia que tú quieres es distinta, adapta el código (número de repeticiones y tiempo de espera entre cada  una.

No hay garantía de que tu proveedor de hosting permita que un único script se ejecute por tanto tiempo, por lo que tienes que probar y monitorear.

Comment: Esto funcionará quizá con riesgo de imprecisiones en cuanto a los tiempos de ejecución y para un número muy limitado de usuarios. Sí hablamos de varias decenas o centenas de miles de usuarios haciendo esto el hosting detectará la trampa, advertirá que la detengas so pena de suspender la cuenta y/o te sugerirá contratar un VPS.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, estoy asumiendo que, de hecho, va a ser el único y haciéndolo para un único sitio. De otra manera, el hostmaster verá la anomalía con lupa, tomará medidas y adios a la posibilidad.

Comment: Tu respuesta fue una idea que se me ocurrió también. Pero también imaginé las complicaciones a las que podría llegar, y quería saber si alguien me podía dar una solución que no me pueda llegar a generar esos problemas ya que es la primera vez que hago trabajo con cron y tal vez había algo más. Muchas gracias igualmente @jachguate

Comment: fuera de que haya un agente que mate el proceso si tarda más de X tiempo, no creo que haya otro problema. Estoy asumiendo que el proceso no va a consumir grandes cantidades de recursos... si lo hace, eso no tiene que ver ya con la manera de _encadenarlo_ para que se ejecute con la frecuencia que quieres.